# matlab; compiling custom made trained deep nn with Library Compiler for calling from Python

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I tried to compile in matlab with Library Compiler my custom-made trained Deep Neural Network to package it for calling from Python.
How can I compose the Support Package for it as exists for example, for resnet50 network here: ...SupportPackages<version>\toolbox\nnet\supportpackages\resnet50?

Thanks

compiling with Library Compiler

Comment: Hi there, can you also share your source code~